# Не находит модуль OWindows.tpu (ошибка 15) в Borland Pascal 7.0

Tags: pascal, borland

Для универа. В программе нужно использовать модуль `uses OWindows;` В методических рекомендациях было сказано, что можно выполнять в Borland Pascal 7.0. Но при запуске программа ругается:

> не найден файл OWindows.tpu (ошибка 15).

Где-то можно взять и доустановить этот модуль? Или я использую неправильную среду разработки?

Answer (score 1):

`uses OWindows;` сообщает о том что нужно использовать модуль OWINDOWS.TPW (OWL Windows unit) являющийся частью библиотеки [Object Windows Library (OWL)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Windows_Library).

Для использования данной библиотеки необходим Borland Pascal With Objects 7.01, в составе [дистрибутива](https://winworldpc.com/product/borland-pascal/7x) которого она присутствует (DISK 10, OWL.ZIP)